# Send mouse click to another window c#

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to simulate a left-click at the window (background) x/y coordinates.

I have searched and found a lot of stuff to simulate mouseclicks to other windows but it does not work 100% well.

My code:

```
private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201; //Left mousebutton down
private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;   //Left mousebutton up

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public void SimulateMouseLeft(IntPtr hwnd, int x,int y)
{
    int coordinates = x | (y << 16);
    //PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)coordinates);
    //PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)coordinates);
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x1, (IntPtr)coordinates);
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)0x1, (IntPtr)coordinates);
    //send left button up
    //PostMessage(hwnd, 0x202, (IntPtr)0x1, (IntPtr)coordinates);
}
```

If I start this code, and simulate a click to another window, then the other window gets a left click but not at x/y. The click is at the same position then my mouse is and after the click my mouse jumps to another position on the screen.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you don't realize that the mouse position is reported in *relative* coordinates.  ScreenToClient() required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking mouse by sending messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818192/clicking-mouse-by-sending-messages)